# Export to .xlsx script error via Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I need to export campaign statistics to .xlsx, which is stored in Google Drive. I substitute the link to this document in the script, and I get this error:

> "Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1S_rjqsgbjyTKXEo14j_m2xtoIwgHCFi1. (file Code.gs, line 18)".

In the privacy parameters of the document, "editing for everyone who has the link" is configured.
How do I solve the problem?
I tested these two links:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S_rjqsgbjyTKXEo14j_m2xtoIwgHCFi1/edit#gid=1649084583/
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_rjqsgbjyTKXEo14j_m2xtoIwgHCFi1/view?usp=sharing

Here is the script itself.

```
function main() {
 // 

 var url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_rjqsgbjyTKXEo14j_m2xtoIwgHCFi1/view?usp=sharing/';
 var datasheet = 'Ali_web_all_acc_export.xlsx';
 var columns = 'CampaignName, AdvertisingChannelType, Cost, Date';
 var report = 'CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
 var selector = 'CampaignName DOES_NOT_CONTAIN "Шашлык15loooool"';
 var during = 'YESTERDAY';

 // Функция выгрузки
 exportReportToSpreadsheet(url, datasheet, columns, report, selector, during);
}
function exportReportToSpreadsheet(url, datasheet, columns, report, selector, date) {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(datasheet);
 var report = AdWordsApp.report(
   'SELECT ' + columns + ' ' +
   'FROM ' + report + ' ' +
   'WHERE ' + selector +' ' +
   'DURING '+ date + ' '
   );

 report.exportToSheet(sheet);
}
```

Comment: Is your Google sheet slow? For example, does it regularly take a lot of time to recalculate 
 complicated formulas? This can lead to the type of timeout that you are experiencing.

Comment: I tried to open the Sheet and it says it is in the bin. Is that the issue?